# How do I disable local role acquisition after a workflow transition?

Tags: plone

Using the Intranet workflow, and when the user selects the hide transition to move the content to the private state, I want to disable local role acquisition. I think I'll want to re-enable when they move it back to internal draft.

I can see how this is done by the sharing view within plone.app.workflow. It has a method, update_inherit, that sets `context.__ac_local_roles_block__` to either `True` or `None`.

How might I do something similar with a transition after_script?

- Plone 4.1.5
- plone.app.workflow 2.0.6

---

More info on my use case:

We have two users, contributor_1 and contributor_2, possessing only the Member role globally. At the site root, create a folder and assign the two users local roles to add, edit, and view.

Here is the default private state/manage_permissions:
[image: default private state permissions]

If contributor_1 creates a page and tries to hide it, contributor_2 can still view, edit, and transition it back to internal draft because contributor_2 is inheriting those local roles.

Here is what I first tried:
[image]

While this does effectively make the page private to only contributor_1 and any Manager, contributor_1 cannot share access with contributor_2 while the item is in the private state. No private collaboration. UPDATE: contributor_1 can manipulate the sharing view (ie. they have access to delegate local roles), but delegating those local roles (Contributor, Editor, Reader) does not translate to their respective access since I have revoked the role-permission mapping in the above workflow.

Now, if set back to the default permission map, users can achieve the private state they want by hiding the content item and then going to the sharing tab and disabling local role acquisition. The problem is they don't want to have to remember to click the checkbox on the sharing tab every time they want to hide something.

Comment: Please understand that `__ac_local_roles_block__` (and equivalent checkbox in Sharing tab) is a big hammer; you risk locking yourself out.  If you can clarify why editing /portal_workflow/intranet_workflow/states/private/manage_permissions is not sufficient to accomplish your goals, I will take a crack at answering your question.

Comment: Users want to be able to make something private to themselves (Owner role), but they also want to be able to hand out select access via the Sharing tab. If I reduce the permissions to only the Owner, delegating Editor role to another user does not actually give the other user the access to edit the content.

Comment: The problem you've describe is solvable by customizing your workflow permissions. No extreme measures are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a utils.py module within my package containing one method: a (nearly) straight copypasta of the update_inherit method the sharing view uses. Then, I imported utils in my package's `__init__.py`.

```
from AccessControl import Unauthorized
from AccessControl.SecurityInfo import ModuleSecurityInfo
from Acquisition import aq_base
from Products.CMFCore import permissions
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

security = ModuleSecurityInfo( 'united.policy.utils' )

security.declarePublic('update_inherit')
def update_inherit(context, status=True, reindex=True):
    """Enable or disable local role acquisition on the context.

    Returns True if changes were made, or False if the new settings are the
    same as the existing settings.
    """
    portal_membership = getToolByName(context, 'portal_membership')

    if not portal_membership.checkPermission(permissions.ModifyPortalContent,
                                             context):
        raise Unauthorized

    block = not status
    oldblock = bool(getattr(aq_base(context), '__ac_local_roles_block__',
                            False))

    if block == oldblock:
        return False

    if block:
        # If user has inherited local roles and removes inheritance, locally
        # set roles he inherited before to avoid definitive loss of access
        # (refs #11945)
        user = portal_membership.getAuthenticatedMember()
        context_roles = user.getRolesInContext(context)
        global_roles = user.getRoles()
        local_roles = [r for r in context_roles if r not in global_roles]
        if local_roles:
            context.manage_setLocalRoles(user.getId(), local_roles)

    context.__ac_local_roles_block__ = block and True or None
    if reindex:
        context.reindexObjectSecurity()

    return True
```

Then, I created two scripts within my `./profiles/default/workflows/intranet_workflow/scripts/` directory bound to their respective transitions:

after_hide.py

```
## Script (Python) "after_hide"
##bind container=container
##bind context=context
##bind namespace=
##bind script=script
##bind subpath=traverse_subpath
##parameters=review_state
##title=
##
from united.policy.utils import update_inherit

update_inherit(review_state.object, False)
```

after_show.py

```
## Script (Python) "after_show"
##bind container=container
##bind context=context
##bind namespace=
##bind script=script
##bind subpath=traverse_subpath
##parameters=review_state
##title=
##
from united.policy.utils import update_inherit

update_inherit(review_state.object, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

As SteveM already commented, the workflow tool can handle this for you.

1. You need need to manage all the necessary permission with your workflow, this depends on your needs.
   UPDATE: You workflow has to manage the "Delegate Roles XYZ [Reader/Contributor/etc.]" and "Change local roles" permissions. This way the user "contributor_1" can delegate roles in the "Private" area.
2. Do NOT acquire any permission settings on your `hidden` state.
   [image: plone workflow state permissions]
3. In your case the Owner (probably the manager too) needs some permissions to view/edit/changestate.

Another hint for defining workflows.
Check [this package](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.lawgiver) it generally manages all the permissions in action groups, like View (View, Access content permissions, etc) or Add (Add Folders, Add portal content, Add..., etc.) All Plone default permissions are mapped to the right action group, and it let's you create a workflow within 5 minutes. The best part is, you can write the workflow in human readable specification file (custom DSL).